# PHP MySQL is taking 0.8s to 3s to load on search query, how to speed up

Tags: php, mysql, performance

my MySQL table is in this structure:

```
|id|title|duration|thumb|videoid|tags|category|views
|1||Video Name|300|thumb1.jpg|134|tag1|tag2|tag3|category|15
|2||Video Name2|300|thumb2.jpg|1135|tag2|tag3|tag4|category|10
```

Table contains about 317k rows.

Query is:

```
SELECT id,title,thumb FROM videos WHERE tags LIKE '%$keyword%' or title LIKE '%$keyword%' order by id desc limit 20
```

And this is taking 0.8s to 3s to load results.

Im new in php/mysql, how can I speed up these queries, suggestions please, thank you.

Comment: You could try MATCH AGAINST in where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this search construct:

```
 column LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

The leading `%` wildcard character definitely defeats the use of indexes to do these searches.  How to cure this terrible performance problem?  You could use FULLTEXT search, about which you can read. Or, you could try to organize your tables so

```
 column LIKE 'keyword%'
```

will find what you need, and then index the columns being searched.  To do this, you would create a tag table, with a name and id for each distinct tag. This table will have a primary key on the id, and a unique key on the tag.  E.g.

```
 tag_id |   tag
 1      |   drama
 2      |   comedy
 3      |   horror
 4      |   historical
```

The you would create another table, known in the trade as a join table, with two ids in it. The primary key of this table is a composite of the two columns. You also need a non-unique index on the tag_id field.

```
 video_id  |  tag_id
  1        |  1
  1        |  4
```

This sample data gives video with id = 1 the tags "drama" and "historical."

Then to match tags you need

```
 SELECT v.id, v.title, v.thumb
   FROM video AS v
   JOIN tag_video  AS tv ON       v.id = tv.video_id
   JOIN tag        AS t  ON  tv.tag_id = t.tag_id
  WHERE t.tag IN ('drama', 'comedy')
```

This will look up your tags very fast, and let you look up multiple ones in a single query if you wish.

It won't help with your requirement for full text search on your titles, however.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try but this tags table will be with about 5,000,000 rows, so will look up fast too?

Comment: Do you actually have five million distinct values of the `tag.tag` column? Really? That's a lot! If that's true, don't use a join table with a pair of id columns, but instead just put `video_id` and `tag` into your `tag` table.  Lookups on join tables (tables with pairs of ids) are very fast indeed. Lookups that search for `column = 'string'` are also very fast if the `column` has an index.

Comment: I created 2 tables and moved tags there how you suggested, now tag table have 35,040 rows (containing unique tags) and the the join table with 3,949,725 rows, and the query is taking <0.01 so is perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The only other suggestion I can throw in is to have a multi-part index of

```
( tags, title, id )
```

This way, it can utilize the index to qualify the WHERE clause criteria for both tags and title, and have the ID for the order by clause without having to go back to the raw data pages.  Then, when records ARE found, only for those entries does it need to actually retrieve the raw data pages for the other columns associated with the row.

Comment: The query will still have to perform a full index scan in this case, but it's true, it will reduce hard-drive thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**
define indexes on title and keyword fields.

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `videos` ADD INDEX (`title`);
ALTER TABLE `videos` ADD INDEX (`keyword`);
```

Comment: tried your code but I see this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key(10))' at line 1"

Comment: queries changed, try again.

Comment: added these 2 indexes but seems about same speed of loading

Comment: Indexes don't help with leading wildcards, unfortunately.